# Is Primefaces Wizard lazy loaded

Tags: primefaces

Is p:wizard lazy loaded or are all tabs loaded the first time the view is loaded?

I have a page that is slow to load and am looking at optimizing it, but cannot find any information on this particular behavior of the wizard component

Comment: It's really easy to know, you can view the source and observe..

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it looks like it is lazy loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Primefaces User Guide ver 5.1 page 504 I quote:

**AJAX and Partial Validations**

Switching between steps is based on ajax, meaning each step is *loaded dynamically with ajax*.
Partial validation is also built-in, by this way when you click next, only the current step is validated,
if the current step is valid, next tab’s contents are loaded with ajax. Validations are not executed
when flow goes back."

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not lazy loaded, when do firebug primeface wizard showcase I can see second tab contents. You need to handle it yourself. Either make it rendered true on submit or create multiple pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I used Chrome to inspect the elements and it looks more like the component is lazy loaded. Even the wizard showcase, the only references to the other tabs are for the source portion. Please confirm